# Javascript variable declaration & scope

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var process = function (test) {
      var i = test;
      this.echo = function () { console.log(i); };
    };
    var test = 'hai';
    var hai = new process(test);
    hai.echo();
    test = 'sorry';
    hai.echo();
</script>
</head>
<body style='height:1000px;width:100%'>
</body>
```

On executing the above test script I'm getting 'sorry' twice which I expected to be 'hai' then 'hai'.

When I change line 5 as [gave a random try]

```
var i = (function () {return test;})();
```

I got it 'hai' & 'hai'

How does it work in the case 2 & why didn't it in case 1?

AFAI, javascript does variable hoisting and because of that *test* will be initialized to *undefined* in the beginning of scope and will be reassigned as and when it is assigned with the values. But here that didn't help me out.

Comment: Your code displays `"hai"` twice for me.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice my mistake voting to delete my own question

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing *pass by reference* with *pass by value*.  JavaScript [only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/518069/94197) allows the latter (despite what you may read elswhere).

In this case, you're passing the value `"hai"` to the `process` constructor.  That value is then stored, in the inner scope, to the `i` variable.  Changing the value of `test` after that will not change the value of `i`.

Neither of your test cases work how you expected, for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Your quoted code does not behave as you've described. But trying to answer the question anyway, here's your code with some inline explanation:

```
var process = function (test) {
  var i = test;

  // Here you're creating a "closure" over the context of
  // this specific call to this function. So the `i` local
  // variable lives on, even after this function call
  // terminates.
  this.echo = function () { console.log(i); };
};

// This `test` variable is *completely and totally* unrelated to the
// `test` argument to your function above. They do not interact in
// any way.
var test = 'hai';

// Here, yu're passing the *value* of the `test` variable ("hai")
// into the function. The function has no reference to the `test`
// variable at all (er, not a relevant way; details below). From
// the function's point of view, it's *exactly* like
// `var hai = new process("hai");`
var hai = new process(test);

// This will show "hai"
hai.echo();

// This will also show "hai", because again, the `i` in the `echo`
// function is the local variable in the call to `new process` above;
// it is in no way whatsoever related to the `test` variable here.
test = 'sorry';
hai.echo();
```

More to explore (in my blog): [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

---

*Details on my note about how the `process` function doesn't have a **relevant** reference to the `test` variable: Technically, the function you're assigning to `process` does have a reference to the `test` variable because it's a closure over the scope in which the `test` variable is defined. But it's not* using *that, because it has its own `test` argument and that symbol shadows (overrides) the one from the containing scope. None of which has anything to do with your passing `test` into the* call to *the `process` function, which is why it's irrelevant.*

Answer (score 0):

It will display 2 time hai. It is not possible to show sorry twice with this script as stored variable `i` in locale scope of `function echo` and `i` is set only once to `hai`